# Error Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java, hilos, excepciones, main

Desarrollar un menú interactivo es una tarea común en programación, pero la aparición de errores puede volverse desafiante. El problema que describes, donde el código funciona correctamente en una ocasión pero luego arroja una excepción, es una situación que a menudo desconcierta a los programadores. Es crucial entender las posibles causas detrás de este comportamiento.

En tu escenario, parece que estás utilizando un objeto Scanner para obtener la opción seleccionada por el usuario. Este enfoque es susceptible a una excepción específica que se presenta cuando se combinan los métodos nextInt() y nextLine() en Java.

La excepción puede surgir debido al comportamiento de nextInt(), que lee únicamente el número y deja el carácter de nueva línea (\n) pendiente en el búfer. Posteriormente, al intentar leer una línea completa con nextLine(), este recoge la línea en blanco dejada por el carácter de nueva línea pendiente, provocando la excepción.

Es fundamental revisar cómo interactúas con el Scanner y considerar ajustes en la secuencia de métodos para evitar este conflicto. La coherencia en la lectura y manejo de entrada es esencial para evitar excepciones y garantizar un funcionamiento fluido de tu programa. Explorar alternativas, como el uso de métodos específicos para cada tipo de entrada, podría ser una estrategia efectiva para prevenir este tipo de errores en tu menú interactivo.

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        credito Credito = new credito(null, null, null, null, 0, 0, false, 0, 0);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int opc = 0;

        while(opc != 7){
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("\t Bienvenido al Sistema de Gestión de Usuarios");
            System.out.println("1. Cargar Usuario");
            System.out.println("2. Ingresar Usuario");
            System.out.println("3. Valores de los Bancos");
            System.out.println("4. Validación");
            System.out.println("5. Plan de crédito");
            System.out.println("6. Eliminar Usuario");
            System.out.println("7. Salir");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Seleccione una opción: ");

            try {
                opc = scanner.nextInt();
            }catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                System.out.println("Error: No such element.");
            }

            try {
                String input = scanner.nextLine();
                opc = Integer.parseInt(input.trim());
    
                switch (opc) {

                    case 1:
                        Credito.Cargar();
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        Credito.Ingresar();
                        break;
                        
                    
                    case 3:

                        try {
                            Credito.Banco();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            System.out.println("Archivo no encontrado.");
                        } 
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        try {
                            Credito.verificar();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        }
                        break;
                        
                    case 5:
                        try {
                                Credito.simular();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("Error de algún tipo.");
                            }
                        break;

                    case 6:
                        try {
                                Credito.Eliminar();
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            System.out.println("Archivo no encontrado.");      
                            }
                        break;

                    case 7:
                        System.out.println("Hasta pronto :)");
                        break;

                    default:
                        System.out.println("Opción no válida");
                        break;

                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Error: Ingrese un número válido.");
            }
        }
        
        scanner.close();
    }
}

class usuario {
    private String NumeroDoc;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private Date fechaNacimiento;
    private double SalarioMen;
    private int score;
    private boolean aprobado = false;
    private double monto;
    private int plazo;
    static File Directorio = new File("/Users/juanfelipeguerreroarias/Documents/U /Programacion Avanzada/Proyecto 2/Usuarios");

    public usuario(String NumeroDoc, String nombre, String apellido, Date fechaNacimiento, double SalarioMen, int score,boolean aprobado ,double monto, int plazo) {
        this.NumeroDoc = NumeroDoc;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
        this.SalarioMen = SalarioMen;
        this.score = score;
        this.aprobado = aprobado;
        this.monto = monto;
        this.plazo = plazo;
    }

    // Getters de la clase

    public String getNumeroDoc() {
        return NumeroDoc;
    }
    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }
    public String getApellido(){
        return apellido;
    }
    public Date getFechaNacimiento(){
        return fechaNacimiento;
    }
    public double getSalarioMen(){
        return SalarioMen;
    }
    public int getScore(){
        return score;
    }
    public double getMonto(){
        return monto;
    }
    public int getPlazo(){
        return plazo;
    }
    public boolean getAprobado(){
        return aprobado;
    }

    // Métodos

    private static File buscar(String NumeroDoc) throws FileNotFoundException{
        try{
            File[] archivos = Directorio.listFiles();

            for(File file : archivos){
                if (file.getName().equals(NumeroDoc)){
                    return file;
                }
                if(file.isDirectory()){
                    File resultado = buscar(NumeroDoc);
                    if(resultado != null){
                        return resultado;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("No se pudo encontrar el usuario: " + NumeroDoc);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void Cargar(){
        try {
            try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
                System.out.println("Ingrese el número de Documento: ");
                String Archivo = sc.nextLine();
                sc.nextLine();

                File archivo = buscar(Archivo);
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(archivo);
                sc.nextLine();

                usuario usuario = new usuario(null, null, null, null, 0, 0, aprobado, 0, 0);

                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String[] linea = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
                    if (linea.length == 8) {
                        nombre = linea[0].trim();
                        apellido = linea[1].trim();
                        String fechaNacimientoStr = linea[2].trim();
                        fechaNacimiento = null;
                        try {
                            fechaNacimiento = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(fechaNacimientoStr);
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            System.err.println("Error al analizar la fecha de nacimiento: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                        SalarioMen = Double.parseDouble(linea[3].trim());
                        score = Integer.parseInt(linea[4].trim());
                        aprobado = Boolean.parseBoolean(linea[5].trim());
                        monto = Double.parseDouble(linea[6].trim());
                        plazo = Integer.parseInt(linea[7].trim());

                        // Crear un objeto Usuario con los datos
                        usuario = new usuario(archivo.getName(), nombre, apellido, fechaNacimiento, SalarioMen, score, aprobado, monto, plazo);
                    }
                }

                
                System.out.println("Número de documento: " + usuario.getNumeroDoc());
                System.out.println("Nombre: " + usuario.getNombre());
                System.out.println("Apellido: " + usuario.getApellido());
                System.out.println("Fecha de nacimiento: " + usuario.getFechaNacimiento());
                System.out.println("Salario mensual: " + usuario.getSalarioMen());
                System.out.println("Score: " + usuario.getScore());
                System.out.println("Monto: " + usuario.getMonto());
                System.out.println("Plazo: " + usuario.getPlazo());


                scanner.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Archvio no encontrado");
        }
        
    }

    public void Ingresar(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese el número de Documento: ");
        String Archivo = sc.nextLine();

        File archivo = new File(Directorio, Archivo);

        
        try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(archivo, false); // "false" para reemplazar el contenido
             BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter)) {

            System.out.println("Ingrese el Nombre: ");
            String nombre = sc.nextLine();
            sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Ingrese el Apellido: ");
            String apellido = sc.nextLine();
            sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Ingrese la Fecha de nacimiento con este formato (YYYY-MM-DD): ");
            String fechaNacimientoStr = sc.nextLine();
            sc.nextLine();
            Date fechaNacimiento = null;
            try {
                fechaNacimiento = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(fechaNacimientoStr);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                System.err.println("Error al analizar la fecha de nacimiento: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            System.out.println("Ingrese el Salario mensual: ");
            double SalarioMen = sc.nextDouble();
            sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Ingrese el Score: ");
            int score = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();

            boolean aprobado = false;

            System.out.println("Ingrese el Monto: ");
            double monto = sc.nextDouble();
            sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Ingrese el Plazo: ");
            int plazo = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();

            String linea = nombre + "," + apellido + ","
                          + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(fechaNacimiento) + ","
                          + SalarioMen + "," + score + "," + aprobado + ","+ monto + "," + plazo;

            bufferedWriter.write(linea);
            bufferedWriter.newLine(); 

            System.out.println("Datos escritos en el archivo en el directorio exitosamente.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error al escribir en el archivo: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        sc.close();
    }


  public void Eliminar() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese el número de Documento del usuario que desea eliminar: ");
        String Archivo = sc.nextLine();
        sc.nextLine();

        File archivo = buscar(Archivo);
        
        archivo.delete();

        sc.close();
    }
}

class Banco {
    private String Nombre;
    int Tasa;
    static private File Directorio = new File("/Users/juanfelipeguerreroarias/Documents/U /Programacion Avanzada/Proyecto 2/Bancos");

    public Banco(String Nombre, int Tasa) {
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
        this.Tasa = Tasa;
    }

    private static File buscar(String Banco) throws FileNotFoundException{
        try{
            File[] archivos = Directorio.listFiles();

            for(File file : archivos){
                if (file.getName().equals(Banco)){
                    return file;
                }
                if(file.isDirectory()){
                    File resultado = buscar(Banco);
                    if(resultado != null){
                        return resultado;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("No se pudo encontrar el usuario: " + Banco);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void Cargar() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del banco: ");
        String Archivo = sc.nextLine();
        sc.nextLine();

        File archivo = buscar(Archivo);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(archivo);
        sc.nextLine();

        Banco Banco = new Banco(null,0);

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] linea = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
            if (linea.length == 2) {
                String Nombre = linea[0].trim();
                int Tasa = Integer.parseInt(linea[1].trim());
                Banco = new Banco(Nombre, Tasa);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Nombre del Banco: " + Banco.Nombre);
        System.out.println("Tasa de Interés: " + Banco.Tasa);

        scanner.close();
        sc.close();
    }

    public int getTasa() {
        return Tasa / 100;
    }
}

class credito extends usuario {
    static Banco banco = new Banco(null, 0);
    //private double saldoDeuda;
    double cuotaMensual;

    public credito(String NumeroDoc, String nombre, String apellido, Date fechaNacimiento, double SalarioMen, int score, boolean aprobado,
                   double monto, int plazo) {
        super(NumeroDoc, nombre, apellido, fechaNacimiento, SalarioMen, score, aprobado, monto, plazo);
    }

    public void Banco() throws FileNotFoundException {
        banco.Cargar();
    }   
    public void simular(){
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
            System.out.println("Ingrese el año de inicio del crédito: ");
            int anioInicio = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("Ingrese el mes de inicio del crédito (de 1 - 12): ");
            int mesInicio = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
    
            double montoCredito = getMonto();
            double tasaInteres = banco.getTasa();
            int plazo = getPlazo();
        
            if (montoCredito > 0 && montoCredito >= calcularCuotaMensual(montoCredito, tasaInteres, plazo)) {
                for (int anio = anioInicio; anio <= anioInicio + plazo / 12; anio++) {
                    for (int mes = mesInicio; mes <= 12; mes++) {
        
                        double cuotaMensual = calcularCuotaMensual(montoCredito, tasaInteres, plazo);
        
                        double abonoCapital = montoCredito/plazo;
        
                        double abonoIntereses = calcularIntereses(montoCredito, tasaInteres, plazo);
        
                        System.out.println("Año: " + anio);
                        System.out.println("Mes: " + mes);
                        System.out.println("Cuota Mensual: " + cuotaMensual);
                        System.out.println("Abono a Capital: " + abonoCapital);
                        System.out.println("Abono a Intereses: " + abonoIntereses);
                    }
        
                    mesInicio = 1;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("El monto del crédito es inferior a la cuota mensual.");
            }

            sc.close();
    }

   public static double calcularCuotaMensual(double montoCredito, double tasaInteres, int plazo){
        double numerador= montoCredito;
        double operacion1= 1+tasaInteres;
        double denominador1= (1-Math.pow(operacion1, (-1*plazo)));
        double denominador2= tasaInteres;
        double denominadort= denominador1/denominador2;
        double cuotaMensual = numerador/denominadort;
            if (cuotaMensual < 0) {
                cuotaMensual = 0;
            }
        return cuotaMensual;
    }

    public static double calcularIntereses(double montoCredito, double tasaInteres, double plazo){
        return (montoCredito*tasaInteres)*plazo;
    } 

    public void verificar() throws CreditDontApply {
        LocalDate fechaActual = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate fechaNacimientoLocal = getFechaNacimiento().toInstant().atZone(java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        int Edad = Period.between(fechaNacimientoLocal, fechaActual).getYears();

        double salario30 = getSalarioMen() * 0.3;

        if (Edad >= 18 && Edad <= 70) {
            if (salario30 >= cuotaMensual) {
                if (getScore() >= 700) {
                    System.out.println("Usted aplica para el préstamo.");
                } else {
                    throw new CreditDontApply("Su historial crediticio no cumple con los requisitos.");
                }
            } else {
                throw new CreditDontApply("Su salario no cumple con los requisitos.");
            }
        } else {
            throw new CreditDontApply("Su edad no cumple con los requisitos.");
        }
    }
}
```